# Словить нестандартное событие в Alpine JS

Tags: javascript

На своей страничке использую библиотеку `AlpineJS`. Со стандартными элементами использую директиву `x-model`. Тут вопросов нет, пример из документации:

```
<div x-data={ message:'' }>
...
<input type="text" x-model="message">
<span x-text="message"></span>
...
```

Здесь ввод в элементе `input` связывается со строкой в `span` через реактивную переменную `message`.

Но сейчас мне нужно использовать компонент [datarangepicker](https://www.daterangepicker.com). С ним так не получается. Единственный выход - ловить событие компонента `apply.daterangepicker`. Вот пример:

```
$('#daterange').daterangepicker();
$('#daterange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
  console.log(picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  console.log(picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
});
```

Да, и директива `x-on:apply.daterangepicker` тут тоже не работает. Пробую по-другому...

Но из замыкания я не вижу возвращаемый объект и его поля:

```
function app() {
  return {
    Period: "",
  init: function() {
    $("#book-period").daterangepicker({
      timePicker: true,
      startDate: moment().startOf("hour"),
      endDate: moment().startOf("hour").add(32, "hour"),
      locale: {
        format: "M/DD hh:mm A",
      },
    }).on(
      "apply.daterangepicker",
      function (ev, picker) {
        console.log("Event!");
        // как здесь достучаться до строки Period и присвоить ей значение?
      }
    );
  }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такую задачу решить правильно?!

Comment: ну, если отвечать на твой вопрос в лоб то вот https://pastebin.com/e5EhT3L6

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я вчера примерно так и сделал, но у меня получилось более некрасиво - но идея та же. Прошу тут опубликовать тут ваш ответ в виде ответа) Может кому еще пригодится!

Comment: но alpinejs реактивный движок, а наше решение выглядит далёким от реактивщины

Comment: Хе-хе ... если бы работало x-on:apply.daterangepicker, то да, тогда решение так себе. Но иного выхода нет. Где-то в сети я видел - городили через генерацию событий и их перехват. Но там портянка на пол-листа ради этого. Думаю разработчику alpinejs написать, упросить придумать новую директиву под такие вопросы. Компонентов js в сети валом, и это нужно учитывать. ИМХО.